# Get session using start time and end time in google fit

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-fit

When I tried to get the sessions based on start and end time, I can get only the named sessions(like Morning walking in the image) but not other sessions. Can any one tell me why this kind of data's not fetched.

API:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?startTime=2016-03-08T00:00:00.000Z&endTime=2016-03-08T22:00:00.000Z&access_token=*******

Not only this date but also for all the date, I have gets only the named sessions.

Response:

```
{
    "session": [
        {
            "id": "b514327692edd309:activemode:walking:1457414580406",
            "name": "Morning walking",
            "startTimeMillis": "1457414580406",
            "endTimeMillis": "1457414781711",
            "modifiedTimeMillis": "1457415751927",
            "application": {
                "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness"
            },
            "activityType": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is probably not a session with the other data your thinking about.  Sessions are not mandatory for data.

Comment: Then how can I fetch the data's without using session start time and end time.

Comment: From dataSource-Datasets it return the values like value{intVal: 1 } what it is define.

Comment: The json: {"datasets":{"minStartTimeNs":"1457548200000000000","maxEndTimeNs":"1457595182000000000","dataSourceId":"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps","point":[{"startTimeNanos":"1457574046609000000","endTimeNanos":"1457574106609000000","dataTypeName":"com.google.step_count.delta","originDataSourceId":"derived:com.google.step_count.cumulative:com.google.android.gms:LENOVO:Lenovo A7000-a:5ac578f3:soft_step_counter","value":[{"intVal":1}],"modifiedTimeMillis":"1457595032069"}]}} what is the intVal defined here

Comment: It says in the docs.  https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_instantaneous_readings it will be the number of steps...